# error NoSuchTableError: - when drop table. Flask

Tags: python, flask, alembic

In his application he created alternately three models and the connections between them:

```
class Operation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "operation"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)    
    date_operation = db.Column(db.DateTime)    
    status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('status.id'))
    status = db.Column(db.String(60))    
    contragent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contragent.id'))
    contragent = db.Column(db.String(240))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Operation {}>'.format(self.code)


class Contragent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "contragent"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(360))
    code = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    adress = db.Column(db.String(480))
    inn = db.Column(db.Integer)
    operations = db.relationship('Operation',uselist=False, backref='operat')  

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Contragent {}>'.format(self.name)


class Status(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "status"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(360))    
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    operations = db.relationship('Operation', uselist=False, backref='operat')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Status {}>'.format(self.name)
```

After creating the Status model with `operations = db.relationship ('Operation', uselist = False, backref = 'operat')`
the database broke down.
When attempting to delete the `Status` model before commented out the class Status, an error occurs:

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\testapp>flask db migrate -m "status table"
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ....
        raise exc.NoSuchTableError(table.name)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: status
```

What causes the error and how can I delete the Status table to create the correct link again?

Answer (score 0):

you have used status.id as foreign key in Operation table.Remove all references to Status table and then try to delete the table. Maybe that'll solve the problem for you.

Comment: Did not help.When I removed from the model the indication of the primary key from Operation and tried to apply the changes to the same error: `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: status`